# Retain function and creation a of new table in python panda as SAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sas

Recently, I am converting from SAS to Python pandas. One question I have is that does pandas have a retain like function in SAS.

My SAS code is:

```
 data df1;
retain col3 "    ";
set df;
by ID  ;
if first.ID  then col3=col1;
else   col3=col3;
```

the other condition i have is in SAS code is:

```
 data df1;
retain col3;
set df;
by ID  ;
if first.ID  then col3=1;
else   col3=col3+1;
```

Next SAS code which i am trying to convert is shown below:

```
   proc sql;
   create table t1 as
     select 
      c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, flag, max(flag) as MAX_flag
   from t1
    group by c1, c2, c3,  c5;
  run;
```

I tried it in pandas as below but seems i am making some silly mistakes. If anyone know how to replicate above sas code block3 into pandas

```
  t1=t1[['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']]
  t1.loc[:,'Max_flag']=t1['flag'].max()
  t1.groupby(['c1','c2','c3','c5'])
```

In my eg. col3 is B and col1 is a.
The condition on which it should be done is
     df.groupby(['ID'],as_index=False).first()

I have 2 columns ID, A.
my requirement is Input data df1:

```
 ID    A
  1    a
  1    b
  2    c
  1    p
  2    q
```

Output dataframe should have one more column name as B. It will group by ID.first(). and copy the data of col A to col B for all the grouped ID.

Output should be df1

```
 ID    A    B
  1    a    a
  1    b    a
  2    c    c
  1    p    a
  2    q    c

 **My key requirement is to convert above SAS code to Pnadas**
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of input and output data?

Comment: Input would be like table of say 10 columns having id column... and i need output data should contain table of 11 columns with values in our new column i.e. col_1 from col_2. Also  no. of records needs to be same in new dataframe also.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and include example data? It will make it much more readable and allow others to understand what do you ask better. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for advices on how to do it better.

Comment: Thanks for the data, but it doesn't explain what are you going to do. Current data suggests that simple `df['col4']=df['col1']` will work, but I believe you are asking about something more complicated. Could you please give data example that will explain what it is needed to do?

Comment: actually i need to convert that sas code which i mentioned into pandas. Yes you are correct its a simple data i need to do complex transformation. what i need is as of now is covert the sas code into pyspark and get the same result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide *simpl*e data example that makes it clear what transformation do you need? You provide SAS code as an explanation but I have no experience with SAS so I cannot understand from that code what is needed. Of course, you can just wait until somebody who knows both SAS and pandas appear and answer your question, but in my opinion it is much better to make your question understandable by those who know only pandas. It will reduce the time you need to wait before you get an answer.

Comment: @user07, as Ilya V. Schurov has already said you would better provide [a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or you will have to wait for rare experts that know both SAS __and__ Pandas/PySpark. Pleas read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). IMO providing a small reproducible data set (3-5 rows) and desired data set will increase the chance to get an answer dramatically...

Comment: @Ilya V. Schurov, I have updated my question do you have any idea how to implement above scinero in pandas

Answer (score 2):

Consider a `merge` with `groupby.first()`:

```
df = df.merge(df.groupby('ID').first().reset_index(), on='ID').rename(columns={'A_x':'A', 'A_y':'B'})

#    ID  A  B
# 0   1  a  a
# 1   1  b  a
# 2   1  p  a
# 3   2  c  c
# 4   2  q  c
```

This can also be generalized with `groupby.nth()` which is zero based. Below takes the second value in each ID:

```
df = df.merge(df.groupby('ID').nth(1).reset_index(), on='ID').rename(columns={'A_x':'A', 'A_y':'B'})

#    ID  A  B
# 0   1  a  b
# 1   1  b  b
# 2   1  p  b
# 3   2  c  q
# 4   2  q  q
```

And as well as `groupby.last()`:

```
df = df.merge(df.groupby('ID').last().reset_index(), on='ID').rename(columns={'A_x':'A', 'A_y':'B'})

#    ID  A  B
# 0   1  a  p
# 1   1  b  p
# 2   1  p  p
# 3   2  c  q
# 4   2  q  q
```

Comment: above answer is correct for if first.ID .. then i want to keep the value same. but if not first.ID and then i need to change the values how i can achieve this ?   I mean this if first.ID is condition for me on basis of this i have set values as if and else. How i will set value for else condition ??

Comment: Please re-phrase your comment as I cannot understand. The `groupby.first()` here yields the same as your desired `df1` output in above question (just a changed ID ordering). If you are changing your original requirement, please ask a separate StackOverflow question.

Comment: i have edited my question. i am not changing my original requirement just adding one else condition for which i need to update records. basically i need to convert above SAS code to pandas or pyspark

Comment: What is the SAS data input? I am not seeing a col3.

Comment: its a new column in dataframe which will get add

Comment: I am not understanding. I do have SAS and I just ran your first code block which exactly matches the answer here for `groupby.first()` (just different col names). Your second is looking for a running group count: `df['B'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()+1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129079/discussion-between-user07-and-parfait).

Comment: above condition is not working. the else part of SAS code block 1 is not getting executed. it would be really helpful if can help me to show the else condition as well. for groupby(id).first() block of sas code equivalent in pandas

Comment: Parfait.. your code is working but i have many columns and group by will be done one 1 columns only. So while applying your code merge i am getting so many _x and _y columns ... how to avoid them and get only 1 extra column ?

Answer (score 0):

Form what you have tried, looks like you want to have 'col4' equal to 'col2' if 'col1' is not blank, otherwise 'col4' should be blank. So you do not need group-by.
Here is how you do the case the case I explained here:

```
In [80]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a','b','c'],[2,'e','r','g'], [3,'BLANK', '', '']], columns=['ID','col1', 'col2','col3'])

In [81]: df
Out[81]: 
   ID   col1 col2 col3
0   1      a    b    c
1   2      e    r    g
2   3  BLANK          

In [82]: df['col4'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 'BLANK', 'BLANK', df['col2'])

In [83]: df
Out[83]: 
   ID   col1 col2 col3   col4
0   1      a    b    c      b
1   2      e    r    g      r
2   3  BLANK            BLANK
```

Comment: alivar thanks for your answer. but my actually requirement is to convert my sas code into pyspark or panda dataframes. i need to get same result of sas code as in my panda dataframes

Comment: as in sas it is being used as a id.first if its true then only it should get assign the col1 value to col4 else keep col4 as default. And also i am not sure about how first works in panda. As in sas it will group all the id with first and then copy the records

Comment: That would be great if you update your question with a more clear description. For example, it is not clear what should be the value of col4 if col1 is not blank.